# Winscp is not connecting to my linux redhat 6. How to fix this?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ip, sharing

I am using Winscp to share files between windows 10 & linux 6, but it is not getting connected. I had installed linux 6 on virtual box. Linux IP address is 10.0.2.15 & windows IP address is 192.168.56.1. Can anyone help me to fix this issue. Is there any way to fix this issue.

Comment: WinSCP is not connecting to what type of connection or service on the Linux machine exactly? What does the WinSCP connection definition look like or what parameters are you using to connect with exactly? How do you have the Linux machine setup to allow the connection exactly? I think you're missing some needed detail if you want something more than a guess. To guess though, I say restart both machines and then try again.... That's my guess so let me know if that helps you any.

Comment: Ok I will try restarting both machines.

Comment: I am using it address 10.0.2.15, SFTP, username: root and password: 123456